# Bower -v: Segmentation fault (`core' dumped)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, npm

I'm trying to install bower on my Ubuntu 18.04.
That's what I have done by this time:

```
sudo snap install bower --classic
sudo npm install bower -g
```

By this time it should be installed, but when I run `bower -v` I get the following message:

`Segmentation fault('core' dumped)`

Here are some outputs:

```
which npm
>> /usr/local/bin/npm
npm -v
>> 6.9.0
which node
>> /usr/bin/node
node -v
>> n8.10.0
which nodejs
>> /usr/bin/nodejs
nodejs -v
>> n8.10.0
```

```
npm config list
>> ; cli configs
>> metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
>> scope = ""
>> user-agent = "npm/6.9.0 node/v8.10.0 linux ia32"
>>
>> ; userconfig /home/luis/.npmrc
>> prefix = "/home/luis/.node_modules_global"
>>
>> ; builtin config undefined
>> globalconfig = "/etc/npmrc"
>> globalignorefile = "/etc/npmignore"
>>
>> ; node bin location = /usr/bin/node
>> ; cwd = /home/luis/4Teleco/TFG/TwitterCluster/Proyectos/MABSED/demo-dashboard
>> ; HOME = /home/luis
>> ; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

```
npm list -g --depth=0
>> /home/luis/.node_modules_global/lib
├── bower@1.8.8
├── node@11.13.0
├── nodejs@0.0.0
└── npm@6.9.0
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, the bower installation with snap has some problem working with a nvm installation of node.

I fixed it by uninstalling the snap bower

`sudo snap remove bower`

and installing it using npm,

`npm install -g bower`

then to fix the bower command (it was still looking for the snap location, even tho a `which bower` reported the right one) I had to run

`hash -d bower`